Applications needing different constants of integration on different intervals
It's curious that you can have different constants of integration on intervals.  E.g. if
$$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{llr}
\frac{-1}{x}+a, & x>0\\
\frac{-1}{x}+b, & x<0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
then
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}.$$
Are there situations/applications where different constants of integration on different intervals are needed/required?

You are computing piecewise derivatives. Your domain is not connected, it is separated by the point 0. So there is no coupling condition between the left and the right part.

Indeed!  A point often missed, or quietly passed over in textbooks.  My question asks whether this is ever needed or used?

I think this is a fair question, howbeit of a somewhat elementary nature. I am surprised to see three votes to close within the hour.

Not a research-level question. More appropriate for MSE

Thanks @RobertIsrael for suggesting MSE.  I'm undertaking an educational research project and whether this technical detail from analysis "matters".  It would be helpful to ask in a research forum (i.e. here) whether this opportunity with constants on different connected domains is needed/requires in particular situations/applications. I hope I'm not asking an elementary question in the wrong forum.

The calculus textbook by Salas & Hille set an exercise: find all anti-derivatives of $\sec^2 x.$ It said the answer is $\tan x + C,$ where $C$ is constant. But it should be a piecewise constant, as long as the domain is $\mathbb R$ and not $\mathbb C.$

Thanks @MichaelHardy, yes there are a couple of tutorial examples in textbooks which cover this.  E.g. taking $ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{ax+1}{a-x}\right)$  to be an antiderivative of $ \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is interesting, and related.  All the examples/discussion I've found so far are from a pure mathematics perspective. I'm interested in applications (including pure mathematics techniques) where different constants are needed.
